# Django Error ValueError at /admin/parcare/parking/ 'ParkingForm' has no field named 'parking_off'

Tags: python, django

I created a nice app, but i got this error when trying to change a filed date

> ValueError at /admin/parcare/parking/ 'ParkingForm' has no field named 'parking_off'.

[image]

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
)
```

My admin.py

```
class ParkingModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user", "location","parking_on", "parking_off"]
    list_display_links = [ "location"]
    list_editable = [ "parking_on"]
    list_filter = ["location"]
    search_fields = ["location", "parking_on"]
    date_hierarchy = 'parking_on'
    save_as = True
    save_on_top = True
    change_list_template = 'admin/change_list_graph.html'

    class Meta:
        model = Parking

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not obj:
            user = request.user
            form.base_fields['user'].initial = user
            form.base_fields['email'].initial = user.email
        return form


    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):  # add an additional message
        user = request.user
        messages.info(request, "Dear " + str(user)+ " "+ " please note that your parking plot has been reserved")
        super(ParkingModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Parking, ParkingModelAdmin)
```

This is my full error:

```
ValueError at /admin/parcare/parking/
'ParkingForm' has no field named 'parking_off'.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/parcare/parking/?location__exact=P3
Django Version: 2.1.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
'ParkingForm' has no field named 'parking_off'.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in add_error, line 353
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/Desktop/Dev/parcare/src',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 3 Oct 2018 16:15:47 +0300
```

This is how My models look like. Maybe is this due to the save method?
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
# from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

today = datetime.now().date()
# tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
# now = datetime.now()
# l = now.hour
# m = int(now.strftime("%H"))

class ParkingManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ParkingManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(parking_on__lte=datetime.now())

class Parking(models.Model):
    PARKING_PLOT = (
        ('P1', 'Parking #1'),('P2', 'Parking #2'), ('P3', 'Parking #3'),
        ('P4', 'Parking #4'),('P5', 'Parking #5'), ('P6', 'Parking #6'),
        ('P7', 'Parking #7'),('P8', 'Parking #8'), ('P9', 'Parking #9'),
        ('P10', 'Parking #10'),('P11', 'Parking #11'), ('P12', 'Parking #12'),
        ('P13', 'Parking #13'),('P14', 'Parking #14'), ('P15', 'Parking #15')

    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    parking_on = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date you want to come in the office.',)
    parking_off = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date when you leave')
    numar_masina = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="IF77WXV", blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please insert your license plate number')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="P1", null=True, choices=PARKING_PLOT,help_text='Please select the desired parking plot.')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ParkingManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location + " | " + str(self.parking_on) + " | " + str(self.parking_off)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "parking"
        ordering = ["-parking_on"]
        unique_together = ("parking_on", "location")


    def clean(self):
        if self.parking_on == today:  # merge--vedem dak parcam azi
            raise ValidationError(
                {'parking_on': _('Please book for a date starting tomorrow')})
        if self.parking_off < self.parking_on:  # merge-vedem daca bookam in trecut
            raise ValidationError(
                {'parking_off': _('You cant book for a past date!')})
        #pt useri ca sa nu salveze mai mult decat 1 zi. Cand e nevoie pt admini se comenteaza linia de mai jos
        if self.parking_off != self.parking_on:
                raise ValidationError(
                    {'parking_off': _('You are not allowed to book more  than one day! Please insert the same day as in parking on field!')})


    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        try:
            super(Parking, self).validate_unique()
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError(
                {'location':
                _("Dear " + str(self.user) +
                                  " seems that the parking places " + str(self.location) +
                                  " you want to book, is already taken on " + str(self.parking_on) + " !" +
                                  " Please select another date or other parking location! "
                                  )})

    def save(self):
        list = []
        d = self.parking_on
        while d <= self.parking_off:
            list.append(
                Parking(user=self.user,
                        email=self.email,
                        parking_on=d,
                        parking_off=d,
                        location=self.location,
                        numar_masina=self.numar_masina
                        )
            )
            d = d + timedelta(days=1)
        Parking.objects.bulk_create(list)
```

Comment: Do you need to `makemigrations`?

Comment: I thinnk `"parking_off"` should be inside `list_editable` too.

Comment: that was it! thank you!

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you will have serious issues with `today` being defined as a global - it means it will only be defined once per process at process start time and never change until the next restart. Given how django server processes are usually handled on a typical production setup this will be a lot of fun to debug xD